# Shift a tikz-cd diagram up when wrapping text around it

Tags: align, tikz-cd, wrapfigure, text, wrap

I want to include a `tikz-cd` diagram alongside text, wrapped around it. To do this, I am using the package `wrapfig`. The code looks like this:

```
\documentclass[psamsfonts]{amsart}

\usepackage{quiver}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\tikzcdset{scale cd/.style={every label/.append style={scale=#1},
    cells={nodes={scale=#1}}}}

\title{}
\author{}
\date{}
\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
...
\end{abstract}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{5cm}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=9pt, scale cd=0.9]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{wrapfigure}
Given a short exact sequence of cochain complexes...

\end{document}
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

There is lots of whitespace above the diagram, and the amount of whitespace increases as I add text to the left. How can I shift only the diagram up?

The full, compilable code:

```
\documentclass[psamsfonts]{amsart}

\usepackage{quiver}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\tikzcdset{scale cd/.style={every label/.append style={scale=#1},
    cells={nodes={scale=#1}}}}

\title{}
\author{}
\date{}
\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
...
\end{abstract}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{5cm}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=9pt, scale cd=0.9]
    && \vdots && \vdots && \vdots \\
    \\
    0 && {A^{k+1}} && {B^{k+1}} && {C^{k+1}} && 0 \\
    \\
    0 && {A^{k}} && {B^k} && {C^{k}} && 0 \\
    \\
    0 && {A^{k-1}} && {B^{k-1}} && {C^{k-1}} && 0 \\
    \\
    && \vdots && \vdots && \vdots
    \arrow[from=5-7, to=5-9]
    \arrow["j", from=5-5, to=5-7]
    \arrow["i", from=5-3, to=5-5]
    \arrow[from=5-1, to=5-3]
    \arrow[from=7-1, to=7-3]
    \arrow["i", from=7-3, to=7-5]
    \arrow["j", from=7-5, to=7-7]
    \arrow[from=7-7, to=7-9]
    \arrow["d_A", shorten <=3pt, shorten >=3pt, from=5-3, to=3-3]
    \arrow["d_B", shorten <=3pt, shorten >=3pt, from=5-5, to=3-5]
    \arrow["d_C", shorten <=3pt, shorten >=3pt, from=5-7, to=3-7]
    \arrow["d_C", shorten <=3pt, shorten >=3pt, from=7-7, to=5-7]
    \arrow["d_B", shorten <=3pt, shorten >=3pt, from=7-5, to=5-5]
    \arrow["d_A", shorten <=3pt, shorten >=3pt, from=7-3, to=5-3]
    \arrow[from=9-3, to=7-3]
    \arrow[from=9-5, to=7-5]
    \arrow[from=9-7, to=7-7]
    \arrow[from=3-7, to=3-9]
    \arrow["j", from=3-5, to=3-7]
    \arrow["i", from=3-3, to=3-5]
    \arrow[from=3-1, to=3-3]
    \arrow[from=3-3, to=1-3]
    \arrow[from=3-5, to=1-5]
    \arrow[from=3-7, to=1-7]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: use `\setlength\intextsep{0pt}` in the preamble  -- also enhanced the space for the figure to `6.5cm` so the arrows dont jut out into the margin and  are oriented with the text -- quiver sty was not available with me so commented out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[psamsfonts]{amsart}

% \usepackage{quiver}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\tikzcdset{scale cd/.style={every label/.append style={scale=#1},
    cells={nodes={scale=#1}}}}

\title{}
\author{}
\date{}
\setlength\intextsep{0pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
...
\end{abstract}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{6.5cm}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=9pt, scale cd=0.9]
    && \vdots && \vdots && \vdots \\
    \\
    0 && {A^{k+1}} && {B^{k+1}} && {C^{k+1}} && 0 \\
    \\
    0 && {A^{k}} && {B^k} && {C^{k}} && 0 \\
    \\
    0 && {A^{k-1}} && {B^{k-1}} && {C^{k-1}} && 0 \\
    \\
    && \vdots && \vdots && \vdots
    \arrow[from=5-7, to=5-9]
    \arrow["j", from=5-5, to=5-7]
    \arrow["i", from=5-3, to=5-5]
    \arrow[from=5-1, to=5-3]
    \arrow[from=7-1, to=7-3]
    \arrow["i", from=7-3, to=7-5]
    \arrow["j", from=7-5, to=7-7]
    \arrow[from=7-7, to=7-9]
    \arrow["d_A", shorten <=3pt, shorten >=3pt, from=5-3, to=3-3]
    \arrow["d_B", shorten <=3pt, shorten >=3pt, from=5-5, to=3-5]
    \arrow["d_C", shorten <=3pt, shorten >=3pt, from=5-7, to=3-7]
    \arrow["d_C", shorten <=3pt, shorten >=3pt, from=7-7, to=5-7]
    \arrow["d_B", shorten <=3pt, shorten >=3pt, from=7-5, to=5-5]
    \arrow["d_A", shorten <=3pt, shorten >=3pt, from=7-3, to=5-3]
    \arrow[from=9-3, to=7-3]
    \arrow[from=9-5, to=7-5]
    \arrow[from=9-7, to=7-7]
    \arrow[from=3-7, to=3-9]
    \arrow["j", from=3-5, to=3-7]
    \arrow["i", from=3-3, to=3-5]
    \arrow[from=3-1, to=3-3]
    \arrow[from=3-3, to=1-3]
    \arrow[from=3-5, to=1-5]
    \arrow[from=3-7, to=1-7]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

- The `tikz-cd` diagram is redrawn into far more simple and short form.
- vertical size of the `vdots` on top of diagram are reduced by use of `\smash` command
- For `wrapfigure` is explicit reserved vertical space.

```
\documentclass[psamsfonts]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{}
\author{}
\date{}
\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
Summary of article
\end{abstract}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}
\begin{wrapfigure}[18]{r}{6.4cm}
    \centering
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=2em,
               row sep=7ex,
                cells={nodes={inner xsep=2pt}},
               font=\footnotesize]
        & \vdots 
            & \vdots 
                & \vdots 
                    & ~     \\
0 \rar  & A^{k+1} \uar \rar["i"]
            & B^{k+1} \uar \rar["j"]
                & C^{k+1} \uar \rar
                    & 0     \\
0 \rar  & A^{k} \uar["d_A"] \rar["i"]
            & B^{k} \uar["d_B"] \rar["j"]
                & C^{k} \uar["d_C"] \rar
                    & 0     \\
0 \rar  & A^{k-1} \uar["d_A"] \rar["i"]
            & B^{k-1} \uar["d_B"] \rar["j"]
                & C^{k-1} \uar["d_C"] \rar
                    & 0     \\
        & \vdots \uar 
            & \vdots \uar
                & \vdots \uar 
                    &       \\
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note:
In generally you can remove additional vertical space in `vrapfigure` by adding in preamble the following

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{wrapfigure}{\setlength\intextsep{0pt}}
```

however, in this particular case this seems not to be (visually) sufficient due to position of `\vdots` in cells, i.e above it is small empty space. If this is not a problem, than you can use this settings for `\intextsep` and remove `\smash` from above image code.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to guess the width of the diagram: let TeX compute it.

I also simplified the coding for the diagram: there's no need to double the number of rows and columns and also for counting the positions: just place the arrows in the source cell.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

%\usepackage{quiver}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\tikzcdset{
  scale cd/.style={
    every label/.append style={scale=#1},
    cells={nodes={scale=#1}}
  },
}
\newcommand{\svdots}{\smash{\vdots}\mathstrut}
\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}
\newsavebox{\tikzcdbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{lrbox}{\tikzcdbox}
\begin{tikzcd}[
  scale cd=0.9,
  row sep=2.5em,
  column sep=2em,
  short/.style={shorten <=3pt, shorten >=3pt},
]
& \svdots & \svdots & \svdots \\
0 \arrow[r] &
A^{k+1} \arrow[r,"i"] \arrow[u,short] &
B^{k+1} \arrow[r,"j"] \arrow[u,short] &
C^{k+1} \arrow[r]     \arrow[u,short] &
0
\\
0 \arrow[r] &
A^{k} \arrow[r,"i"] \arrow[u,"d_A", short] &
B^{k} \arrow[r,"j"] \arrow[u,"d_B", short] &
C^{k} \arrow[r]     \arrow[u,"d_C", short] &
0
\\
0 \arrow[r] &
A^{k-1} \arrow[r,"i"] \arrow[u,"d_A", short] &
B^{k-1} \arrow[r,"j"] \arrow[u,"d_B", short] &
C^{k-1} \arrow[r]     \arrow[u,"d_C", short] &
0
\\
& \svdots \arrow[u,short] & \svdots \arrow[u,short] & \svdots \arrow[u,short]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{lrbox}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{\wd\tikzcdbox}
\usebox{\tikzcdbox}
\end{wrapfigure}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `psamsfonts` option is obsolete and only exists for compatibility with 20+ year old documents.

Comment: how about the height -- can we measure the height so that the number of lines in wrapfigure need not be counted

Comment: @jsbibra That's done by `wrapfig` and generally need not be specified; in my answer it isn't.