# Wrapping a tikzcd environment around a paragraph

Tags: tikz-cd, wrapfigure

I have a `definition` environment, in which there are two tikzcd diagrams that I would like the text to wrap around. Specifically, I'd like the diagrams to be to the right of the text, but as in the screenshot below, the figures do not stick to the right of the page. This worked in the post [Shift a tikz-cd diagram up when wrapping text around it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/598753/shift-a-tikz-cd-diagram-up-when-wrapping-text-around-it), which is where my attempt is based off of.

[image]

Here is the full `tex` source code:

```
\documentclass[14pt, a4paper]{extarticle}

% font & text-related
\usepackage{sansmathfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[charter, uppercase=upright]{mathdesign}

% so the compilation does not give a warning
\let\circledS\undefined % here - PS

% math environment/symbol related
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

% for including q.uiver.app diagrams:
\usepackage{quiver}

% paper dimensions, margins
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage[shortlabels, inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{extsizes}

\geometry{margin=.7in, bottom=.8in, top=.6in}

% disables enum separation with enumitem
\setenumerate{noitemsep}

% theorem, proof, example environments
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}

\begin{document}

Returning to our previous constructions, we wish to generalize 
their definitional pattern as much as possible. The third condition 
is already in a categorical state, but the first two conditions may be 
generalized, which is what we will do now.

\begin{definition}[Cone I] 
    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{.3\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
            \& c \\
            \\
            Fj \&\& Fk
            \arrow["{\lambda_j}"', from=1-2, to=3-1]
            \arrow["{\lambda_k}", from=1-2, to=3-3]
            \arrow["F\alpha"', from=3-1, to=3-3]
        \end{tikzcd}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    Let $F: J\to C$ be a diagram. a cone over $F$ (or simply a cone of $F$) is 
    an object $c\in C$, together with a collection of morphisms 
    $(\lambda_j: c\to Fj)_{j\in J}$ such that given any pair of objects $j, k\in J$ 
    and any morphism $\alpha: j\to k \in J$, the following diagram commutes
    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{.3\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
            Fj \&\& Fk \\
            \\
            \& {c'}
            \arrow["{\varepsilon_j}"', from=1-1, to=3-2]
            \arrow["{\varepsilon_k}", from=1-3, to=3-2]
            \arrow["F\alpha", from=1-1, to=1-3]
        \end{tikzcd}
    \end{wrapfigure}
Similarly, a cone under $F$ (or simply a \emph{cocone} of $F$) is an object $c'\in C$, 
along with a collection of morphisms $(\varepsilon_j: Fj\to c')_{j\in J} \in C$ 
such that given any pair of objects and morphisms from $J$ the following diagram again commutes:
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Wrapfigure doesn't work inside lists.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74635) And the theorems are such “lists”.

Answer (score 2):

As @Qrrbrbirlbel states in the comments, `wrapfigure` doesn't work inside lists. But theorems, definitions, etc. are defined as lists.

One possible workaround is to place the definition and diagrams in adjacent `minipage`s.

[image]

```
\documentclass[14pt, a4paper]{extarticle}

% font & text-related
\usepackage{sansmathfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[charter, uppercase=upright]{mathdesign}

% so the compilation does not give a warning
\let\circledS\undefined % here - PS

% math environment/symbol related
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

% for including q.uiver.app diagrams:
%\usepackage{quiver}

% paper dimensions, margins
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage[shortlabels, inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{extsizes}

\geometry{margin=.7in, bottom=.8in, top=.6in}

% disables enum separation with enumitem
\setenumerate{noitemsep}

% theorem, proof, example environments
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}

\begin{document}

Returning to our previous constructions, we wish to generalize 
their definitional pattern as much as possible. The third condition 
is already in a categorical state, but the first two conditions may be 
generalized, which is what we will do now.

\noindent\begin{minipage}{.6\textwidth}\begin{definition}[Cone I]
    Let $F: J\to C$ be a diagram. a cone over $F$ (or simply a cone of $F$) is 
    an object $c\in C$, together with a collection of morphisms 
    $(\lambda_j: c\to Fj)_{j\in J}$ such that given any pair of objects $j, k\in J$ 
    and any morphism $\alpha: j\to k \in J$, the following diagram commutes:

Similarly, a cone under $F$ (or simply a \emph{cocone} of $F$) is an object $c'\in C$, 
along with a collection of morphisms $(\varepsilon_j: Fj\to c')_{j\in J} \in C$ 
such that given any pair of objects and morphisms from $J$ the following diagram again commutes:
\end{definition}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}\centering
        \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
            \& c \\
            \\
            Fj \&\& Fk
            \arrow["{\lambda_j}"', from=1-2, to=3-1]
            \arrow["{\lambda_k}", from=1-2, to=3-3]
            \arrow["F\alpha"', from=3-1, to=3-3]
        \end{tikzcd}
        
        \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
            Fj \&\& Fk \\
            \\
            \& {c'}
            \arrow["{\varepsilon_j}"', from=1-1, to=3-2]
            \arrow["{\varepsilon_k}", from=1-3, to=3-2]
            \arrow["F\alpha", from=1-1, to=1-3]
        \end{tikzcd}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```